# Open Youtube video in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, youtube

The following is the code at this page https://flytimegantt.com

```
 <div className={styles.videoPreview}>
                    <iframe
                        src={`${videoData[router.locale]}?autoplay=0`}
                        title="Flytime"
                        frameBorder="0"
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowFullScreen
                        style={{ width: '960px', maxWidth: '100%', height: '640px', maxHeight: '50vw', resize: 'both' }}
                    />
                </div>
```

The problem is that the video is unclear at the size, is there any way to maximize it for viewing when playing? (I am also open other means too to improve user experience)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Youtube API to achieve this see the example below

```
function playFullscreen (){
  player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile
  
  var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/fregante/pen/GgOvLM